# Automatically import fontyourface fonts

Tags: 9

Is is possible to automatically import selected fontyourface fonts via config? Ideally, this would be just the fonts I've selected, not all from the source API.

I'm in the middle of a D7 -> D9 migration, and I keep having to manually press that 'Import from fontsquirrel_api' button each time I test the migration from scratch. And that entails downloading all 1021 FontSquirrel fonts, rather than just the 4 I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

A few minutes after posing the question, I found a potential solution:
dump the entire `fontyourface_font` table, and then import it during deployment.

It's not quite as elegant as I had hoped, but it'll work if there's nothing better.

(https://www.drupal.org/project/fontyourface/issues/2978933#comment-13847846)